# Mongoose connection to replica set not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am running my own MongoDb Replica Set on Kubernetes.

It has 3 members, I exposed them all via `NodePort`.

**I can connect to it via shell:**

(feel free to connect, it's an empty, isolated example that will be destroyed)

```
mongo mongodb://stackoverflow:practice@134.122.99.184:31064,134.122.99.184:31086,134.122.99.184:32754/thirty3?authSource=admin
```

**However, I cannot connect to it via mongoose 5.11.12 using the same connection string**.

**It only works until mongoose 4.5.8**

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://stackoverflow:practice@134.122.99.184:31064,134.122.99.184:31086,134.122.99.184:32754/thirty3?authSource=admin&replicaSet=thirty3&?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      poolSize: 5,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000, // Timeout after 5s instead of 30s
    })
```

I tried tons of configurations, `gssapiServiceName=mongodb`, `replicaSetName=thirty3` (I checked the replica set name by running `rs.conf()` ) and many more other configurations.

**My question is** - is there something wrong with mongoose handling these types of communications?

I have found similar issues that indicate downgrading as a solution, but downgrading is not ideal unless impossible to fix it normally.

Please try the code samples above, the database is open for connections with the credentials exposed.

Comment: mongoose does not talk to the deployment. Test using the node driver.

Comment: We are using mongoose across the whole codebase, I can't rewrite it all

Answer (score 2):

This configuration works for me in Local MongoDB with a replica set.

```js
await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/movieku", { family: 4 })
```

Source: https://docs.w3cub.com/mongoose/connections

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).